# Password-checking program for webmin

Tags: password

I'm trying to perform password quality checks using pwqcheck (part of passwdq) in webmin.

Unfortunately when I set in "Users and Groups" module settings the "External password-checking program" to the same value that works for samba `check password script`:

```
/usr/bin/pwqcheck -1
```

I get following error when I try to create a user (named `test-user`):

```
Failed to save user : pwqcheck: Error parsing parameter "test-user": Invalid parameter
```

So, **How do I configure Webmin together with pwqcheck?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @HopelessN00b: It's about using it when I'm in full control of it, i.e. *I'm* the service provider it's not about using it only as a user. I think the accepted answer makes it pretty clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by two related issues.

Webmin allows to set how the password and login is passed to the application (as a paramter or on standard input).
This the `Pass username and password to program` option. That's the main reason for the error mentioned in OP.

Unfortunately it isn't possible to specify what and in which order the information is passed to the application -- that's the second problem --, it is hard-coded to either

```
$application "$login" "$password"
```

or as lines passed to standard input in the same order. Both of them are unsuitable for use with `pwqcheck`. With either option it is quite easy to write a wrapper though.

Provided script is for login and password on stdin:

```
#/bin/bash

read login
read password

/usr/bin/pwqcheck -1 <<_EOF_
 ${password}
_EOF_
```